# Adjust Calendar with Scatter Plot in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to generate a different scatter plot whenever I choose a date in my calendar. I'm gonna explain:

The date column contains the dates 01/01/2021 to 04/01/2021. So, for example, if I select the day 01/01, the scatter plot I would like to be generated is as follows: column X consider the DR1,DR2, DR3 and DR4 values for the chosen day, that is, 2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5 and 6. And for column Y, the sum of D1 referring to the chosen day, that is, for the day 01/01, for example, is 5 + 3 + 4 = 12.

This resolved question may help:
[Link Calendar with Scatter Plot in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68878146/link-calendar-with-scatter-plot-in-shiny)

I'll insert an APP structure below to help.

Thank you very much!

```
rm(list=ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)


    function.cl<-function(){
      
      df <- structure(
        list(date = c("2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-02","2021-01-02","2021-01-03",
                    "2021-01-03","2021-01-03","2021-01-03","2021-01-03","2021-01-04","2021-01-04","2021-01-04"),
           D1 = c(5,3,4,5,6,3,4,4,2,3,4,2,2,3), DR1= c(2,4,5,8,9,3,4,4,3,2,3,1,5,4),
           DR2 = c(4,2,5,5,3,3,3,7,3,5,2,2,2,3), DR3  = c(2,2,3,6,7,5,2,2,2,1,6,8,2,5),
           DR4  = c(3,5,6,3,4,5,1,3,2,1,2,7,5,6)),
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
    
    
    
      return(list(
       date = df$date
      ))
      
    }   
    
    
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      
      ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                              br(),
                              
                              tabPanel("",
                                       sidebarLayout(
                                         sidebarPanel(
                                           
                                           uiOutput("date"),
                                           br(),
                                         ),
                                         
                                         mainPanel(
                                           tabsetPanel(
                                             tabPanel("",plotOutput("Graph",width = "95%", height = "600"))),
                                         ))
                              )))
    
    
    server <- function(input, output,session) {
      data <- reactive(function.cl())
      
      output$date <- renderUI({
        all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
        disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")
        
        dateInput(input = "date", 
                  label = "Select Date",
                  min = min(data()$date),
                  max = max(data()$date),
                  value = max(data()$date),
                  format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                  datesdisabled = disabled)
      })
      
     # output$Graph <- renderPlot({
        
        
      #})
    
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is the core problem anyhow related to shiny? Sounds to me like you just want to have a plot generating function that takes date(s) as an input and returns the corresponding plot. Did you try that by yourself or where did you get stuck?

Comment: Actually, I tried but couldn't do this function. That's why I left only the database. I left the structure shiny to ease this visualization issue on different days.

Comment: What exactly do you want to plot? P.S. As it is the only data being returned by function.cl is the date.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. In the dataframe you have 3 rows for each date. what should be there on X-axis and what should be there on Y-axis ?

Comment: X values are the values of DR, referring to the selected date. If it's for 01/01 it's 2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5 and 6. And the Y values are the sum of the D1 values for the selected date, or that is, for D1 5 + 3 + 4 = 12.

Comment: @norie, the app I inserted was just a brief app framework to help. My idea is that the X axis of the scatterplot is the DR values for the chosen date, that is, if it goes to 01/01 it is 2, 4, 5, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5 and 6. And the Y values are the sum of the D1 values for the selected date, or that is, for D1 5 + 3 + 4 = 12

Comment: So you'll have 12 points on the chart for any date selected with the same y-axis value for all of them?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood the final plot that you are looking for but perhaps this is closer.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)

function.cl<-function(){
  
  df <- structure(
    list(date = c("2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-01","2021-01-02","2021-01-02","2021-01-02","2021-01-03",
                  "2021-01-03","2021-01-03","2021-01-03","2021-01-03","2021-01-04","2021-01-04","2021-01-04"),
         D1 = c(5,3,4,5,6,3,4,4,2,3,4,2,2,3), DR1= c(2,4,5,8,9,3,4,4,3,2,3,1,5,4),
         DR2 = c(4,2,5,5,3,3,3,7,3,5,2,2,2,3), DR3  = c(2,2,3,6,7,5,2,2,2,1,6,8,2,5),
         DR4  = c(3,5,6,3,4,5,1,3,2,1,2,7,5,6)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
  
df
  
}   



ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                       uiOutput("date"),
                                       br(),
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel(
                                         tabPanel("",plotOutput("Graph",width = "95%", height = "600"))),
                                     ))
                          )))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  data <- reactive(function.cl())
  
  output$date <- renderUI({
    all_dates <- seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'), as.Date('2021-01-15'), by = "day")
    disabled <- as.Date(setdiff(all_dates, as.Date(data()$date)), origin = "1970-01-01")
    
    dateInput(input = "date", 
              label = "Select Date",
              min = min(data()$date),
              max = max(data()$date),
              value = max(data()$date),
              format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
              datesdisabled = disabled)
  })
  
  output$Graph <- renderPlot({
  
    req(input$date)
    
    sum_data <- data() %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(D1 = sum(D1))
    
    data() %>%
      select(-D1) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('DR')) %>%
      filter(date == input$date) %>%
      left_join(sum_data, by = 'date') %>%
      ggplot(aes(value, D1)) + geom_point()

  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```